# Implementing pagination with mysql (limit and offset)

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, limit, offset

I am implementing a RESTful api that has a GET endpoint that needs to support pagination.  To do so, I have implemented the standard limit and offset query parameters.  When I get to the (mysql) database, I need to fetch the data in an ordered, consistent manner.  I have attempted to use an 'order by' combined with a 'limit x, y' in my query, yet the expected results are not being returned.

**DDL/DML**

Here is the (only) script being used to create the tables/indexes (ddl) and insert the data (dml): https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1.0.0__CreateAssessment.sql.  The contents of the file is also given below:

```
CREATE TABLE ASSESSMENT(
  ISBN BIGINT NOT NULL
, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(32)
, AUTHOR_LAST_NAME VARCHAR(32)
, TITLE VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
, NUMBER_OF_POINTS FLOAT NOT NULL
, IS_VERIFIED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
, READING_LEVEL FLOAT NOT NULL
, CREATED_TEACHER_ID MEDIUMINT
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ASSESSMENT_X01 ON ASSESSMENT(
    ISBN
);

ALTER TABLE ASSESSMENT
ADD CONSTRAINT ASSESSMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(
    ISBN
);

CREATE INDEX ASSESSMENT_X02 ON ASSESSMENT(
    TITLE
);

CREATE INDEX ASSESSMENT_X03 ON ASSESSMENT(
    CREATED_TEACHER_ID
);

INSERT INTO ASSESSMENT(ISBN, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, TITLE, NUMBER_OF_POINTS, IS_VERIFIED, READING_LEVEL, CREATED_TEACHER_ID)
            VALUES(9781976530739, 'Herman', 'Melleville', 'Moby Dick', 65, FALSE, 10.8, 1);

INSERT INTO rc.ASSESSMENT(ISBN, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, TITLE, NUMBER_OF_POINTS, IS_VERIFIED, READING_LEVEL, CREATED_TEACHER_ID)
            VALUES(0486282112, 'Mary', 'Shelley', 'Frankenstein', 22, FALSE, 12.0, 1);

INSERT INTO rc.ASSESSMENT(ISBN, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, TITLE, NUMBER_OF_POINTS, IS_VERIFIED, READING_LEVEL, CREATED_TEACHER_ID)
            VALUES(1503275922, 'Joseph', 'Conrad', 'Heart of Darkness', 36, FALSE, 12.5, 1);

INSERT INTO rc.ASSESSMENT(ISBN, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, TITLE, NUMBER_OF_POINTS, IS_VERIFIED, READING_LEVEL, CREATED_TEACHER_ID)
            VALUES(0679732764, 'Ralph', 'Ellison', 'Invisible Man', 30, FALSE, 9.8, 1);
```

**SQL Query**
The query ran to retrieve entries from the assessment table can be found at: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/src/main/resources/sql.properties .  For convenience, I've also included it below

```
GET_ALL_ASSESSMENTS=SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID FROM ASSESSMENT ORDER BY ISBN ASC
GET_ASSESSMENT_LIMIT_OFFSET=SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID FROM ASSESSMENT ORDER BY ISBN ASC LIMIT :LIMIT, :OFFSET
GET_ASSESSMENT_COUNT=SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ASSESSMENT
```

**Expected Results**
My expected results are given below:

- limit=1,offset=0 -> return list of size one with lowest isbn being returned
- limit=1,offset=1 -> return list of size one with the second lowest isbn being returned
- limit=1,offset=2 -> return list of size one with the third lowest isbn being returned
- limit=1,offset=3 -> return list of size one with the fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=1,offset=x (x>=4) -> return an empty list
- limit=2,offset=0 -> return list of size two with two lowest isbn being returned
- limit=2,offset=1 -> return list of size two with second/third lowest isbn being returned
- limit=2,offset=2 -> return list of size two with third/fourth isbn being returned
- limit=2,offset=3 -> return list of size one with the fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=2,offset=x (x>=4) -> return empty list
- limit=3,offset=0 -> return list of size three with three lowest isbn
- limit=3,offset=1 -> return list of size three with second/third/fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=3,offset=2 -> return list of size two with third/fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=3,offset=3 -> return list of size one with fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=3,offset=x (x>=4) -> return empty list
- limit=x,offset=0 (x>=4) -> return list of size four, with all isbn in it
- limit=x,offset=1 (x>=4) -> return list of size three with second/third/fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=x,offset=2 (x>=4) -> return list of size two with third/fourth lowest isbn being returned
- limit=x,offset=3 (x>=4) -> return list of size one with fourth lowest isbn being returned

**Actual Results**

- limit=1,offset=0 -> empty list returned (sql ran *SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID FROM ASSESSMENT ORDER BY ISBN ASC LIMIT 1, 0*
- limit=1,offset=1 -> list of size one (sql ran *SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID FROM ASSESSMENT ORDER BY ISBN ASC LIMIT 1, 1*)
- limit=1,offset=2 -> list of size two
- limit=1,offset=3 ->
- limit=1,offset=x (x>=4) ->
- limit=2,offset=0 ->
- limit=2,offset=1 ->
- limit=2,offset=2 ->
- limit=2,offset=3 ->
- limit=2,offset=x (x>=4) ->
- limit=3,offset=0 -> empty list (sql ran * SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID FROM ASSESSMENT ORDER BY ISBN ASC LIMIT 3, 0*)
- limit=3,offset=1 ->
- limit=3,offset=2 ->
- limit=3,offset=3 ->
- limit=3,offset=x (x>=4) ->
- limit=x,offset=0 (x>=4) ->
- limit=x,offset=1 (x>=4) ->
- limit=x,offset=2 (x>=4) ->
- limit=x,offset=3 (x>=4) ->

**Questions:**

1. Am I creating the sql correctly?
2. If I am, is this an issue with mysql/how would I remedy this to produce the expected results?
3. If I am not, how do I correct my query to produce the expected results?  Is it as simple as flipping my limit/offset?
4. Any general input on how to implement this functionality would be welcome.

Thanks,
Connor

Comment: Nicely crafted question with clearly defining the requirement  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full marks to the question preparation,

If I see the problem and understood correct, the issue is with the order you place `limit` and `offset`

There are two ways,

Either you explicitly mention the `limit` and `offset` as,

```
SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID 
FROM ASSESSMENT 
ORDER BY ISBN ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

OR

Incase you don't want to mention the word `offset` explicitly we need to pass the `offset` value first and then `limit` value as

```
SELECT ISBN,AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME,AUTHOR_LAST_NAME,TITLE,NUMBER_OF_POINTS,IS_VERIFIED,READING_LEVEL,CREATED_TEACHER_ID 
FROM ASSESSMENT 
ORDER BY ISBN ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

P.S. I didn't test each and individual cases as you mentioned but I think if my understanding correct you know what to do now.

Comment: Thanks Sujitmohanty30, I had went ahead and flipped the parameters, and it looks like that fixed the problem.  This confirms your answer.  Thanks for your help and confirmation! (accepted and upvoted)

Comment: @Connor Butch, may I know the reason of un-accept the answer ? Was I wrong ? You have confirmed and accepted the answer ? Seems to be not right behaviour. Sorry to say

Comment: Someone else commented, and I accepted theirs as well, which I guess unaccepted yours (I'm not on here that often, so I didn't know you could only accept one answer at once).  I've accepted yours again, as it was first.

Comment: @Connor Butch, If I understand your action, you cannot accept two answers at same time but rather you can only up-vote any answer which made contribution and it's totally your choice. You can un-accept an answer after accepting it but with giving  proper reasons ( as I am saying this is not a hard and fast rule but doing things in better way what I feel personally). Thank you for your response and I hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

you have it backwards `LIMIT *OFFSET*, *ROW_COUNT*`
alternatively you can use `OFFSET`

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

So query could be

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 0, 1
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Thanks Jpsh!  This confirms our above findings (I've upvoted and accepted this answer as well)